# Solutions of the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=(1-x)x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In solving the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=(1-x)x$, I can obtain one solution by integrating $\frac{1}{x(1-x)}dx $ with the assumption that $0<x<1$. How can I obtain other solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are trivial constant solutions $x(t) = 1$ and $x(t) = 0$. All the others can be found by separation of variable as you do. It is not necessary to suppose $0<x<1$. It is enough that $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$.

Comment: MathJax works in the title, don't you know?

Comment: No: '*with the assumption that $0<x<1$*'. Yes: '*with the assumption that $x\neq0,1$*'

Comment: @Shaun they are shown in source code on my phone...

Comment: So no other solution exists.

Comment: It's still better to use MathJax than not. I find that the app has that problem though. Stick to the mobile website: I do.

Comment: What does it mean to have $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$ as the subject? Isn't there supposed to be something like $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\big(\cdot \big)$?

Comment: You only need to assume that the initial condition is just not exactly equal to 0 or 1. If it is outside $[0,1]$ then separation of variables still gives solutions but now they are unbounded (exponentially growing).

Comment: @user477343 No. $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ works fine since $x$ is a function of $t$. It's a bit like $y=x^2\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2x$...

Comment: @user477343 It's a function of $t$, implicitly.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Oh yes I was confusing it with $\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(x)$ or something like that. I am only confused with why we would not want to integrate the inverse of $(1-x)x$ as opposed to just itself alone...

Comment: Now I see that my problem is that I don't know how to integrate this function outside $]0,1[$...

Comment: @Jiu It is similar, depending on whether you mean $x>1$ or $x<0$. For $x_0<0$ say you have $\int_{x_0}^x \frac{dy}{y}$. Change variables: $y=-z,dy=-dz$ to get $\int_{-x_0}^{-x} \frac{dz}{z}=\ln(x/x_0)$ (which is the same form as you had for $x>0$ but the expansion looks different).

Comment: @Ian thanks, I just figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing
$$\frac{dx}{(1-x)x}=dt$$ and integrating we get $$x(t)=\frac{e^t}{e^t+C}$$
Note that $$\frac{1}{(1-x)x}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Comment: Could you explain how to integrate this if I don't assume $0<x<1$? I need this for the logarithm to be defined.

Comment: When you integrate $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}$ you get $\log \lvert x \rvert$ and $-\log \lvert 1-x \rvert$. So if $x \neq 0,1$ they are well defined.

Comment: There are also two "special" solutions.

Answer (score 1):

***Another approach..***

$$x'={(1-x)x}$$
$$x'-x=-x^2$$
$$(xe^{-t})'=-(xe^{-t})^2e^t$$
$$ \int \frac {d(xe^{-t})}{(xe^{-t})^2}=-\int e^t dt$$
$$ (xe^{-t})^{-1}=e^t+K \implies x^{-1}=\frac {e^t+K}{e^t}$$
$$  \implies  x=\frac {e^t} {e^t+K}$$

Answer (score 1):

With $y:=1/x$, the equation linearizes

$$-\frac{y'}{y^2}=\left(1-\frac1y\right)\frac1y,$$

$$y'=1-y$$ and

$$y=1+Ce^{-t}=\frac1x.$$

Comment: It's Bernouilli's equation...